# How to find all child controls in an Activity (Android)

Tags: android

How do I find all child controls in an Activity. I want to get an enumeration of all EditTexts, Spinnners and Checkboxes at runtime.

Thanks

Comment: Pretty sure this isn't possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't get a direct enumeration. You'll have to do a recursive walk using `ViewGroup#getChildCount` coupled with `ViewGroup#getChildAt`. Then you'll have to test using `instanceof` and process each view however you want depending on its type.

Comment: Thanks, that sounds like a possible method. I'm (very) new to Android. Can you tell me how to get a handle to the ViewGroup of an activity?